# What is the default generator for CMake in Windows?

Tags: c, visual-studio, cmake, generator, nmake

When running CMake on one PC, CMake generates NMake files by default. On another, it generates a Visual Studio project.

I know I can override the default by adding `-G "NMake Makefiles"` to the end of my CMake statement, but I want to know why it defaults to Visual Studio projects on one and NMake files on another.

Comment: Is it the same version of CMake?

Comment: Yes, the version is 2.8.4 on both machines.

Comment: I actually found a solution, but it won't allow me to post it for another seven hours... <.<

Comment: You can probably post your solution now @chrisfinley - that's seven years now :)

Comment: @user2023370 - Ha! I did post it later that day...good thing too, because there's no way I'd remember it now if I hadn't ;-)

Comment: Ah so you did. A pity editing the source code is still the best solution in 2018 :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following is from the CMake Source (version 2.8.4: cmake.cxx: starting line 2039):

```
  // Try to find the newest VS installed on the computer and
  // use that as a default if -G is not specified
  std::string vsregBase =
    "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\";
  struct VSRegistryEntryName
  {
    const char* MSVersion;
    const char* GeneratorName;
  };
  VSRegistryEntryName version[] = {
    {"6.0", "Visual Studio 6"},
    {"7.0", "Visual Studio 7"},
    {"7.1", "Visual Studio 7 .NET 2003"},
    {"8.0", "Visual Studio 8 2005"},
    {"9.0", "Visual Studio 9 2008"},
    {"10.0", "Visual Studio 10"},
    {0, 0}};
  for(int i =0; version[i].MSVersion != 0; i++)
    {
    std::string reg = vsregBase + version[i].MSVersion;
    reg += ";InstallDir]";
    cmSystemTools::ExpandRegistryValues(reg);
    if (!(reg == "/registry"))
      {
      installedCompiler = version[i].GeneratorName;
      }
    }
  cmGlobalGenerator* gen
    = this->CreateGlobalGenerator(installedCompiler.c_str());
  if(!gen)
    {
    gen = new cmGlobalNMakeMakefileGenerator;
    }
  this->SetGlobalGenerator(gen);
  std::cout << "-- Building for: " << gen->GetName() << "\n";
```

It appears that CMake looks at the Windows Registry to determine which generator to use. It searches the Visual Studio registry subkeys (6.0, 7.0, etc) in `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\` for an entry called `InstallDir`. If one is found, it uses the corresponding generator. (It will use the newest version of Visual Studio available.) Otherwise, it uses the NMake generator.

Note that the `InstallDir` entry is not always present, even when a particular version of Visual Studio is installed. This may have to do with installation settings or a particular version of Visual Studio (e.g. it seems that the "Express" versions of Visual C++ do not add this entry.)

It is, of course, possible to override the default setting by appending `-G {Generator Name}` to the end of your CMake command.

Comment: For posterity: there is [an entry in the CMake mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg18033.html) that addresses this issue.  To change the default generator, it seems you need to either modify the CMake source and recompile or write a small batch file that adds the `-G` option to substitute the generator when none is specified.

Comment: Visual Studio 14 community does not have `InstallDir`. I want to automate 64bit selection of `cmake` generator, and there seems to be no easy way.

Comment: Actually it is there, just should make sure to look inside `W6432Node` if Windows itself is 64bit, because VS is a 32bit application.

Comment: Also [this](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmake.cxx#L1422) is the line in the latest cmake for anyone looking.

Comment: @dashesy I ran into the same problem. Could you let me know how exactly did you automate 64bit selection for cmake? I tried creating the InstallDir registry and it does nothing

Comment: @user3667089 [This](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/v19.1/setup.py#L177) is the python implementation. It reads the registry in the same way that CMake does.

Comment: @dashesy Does that means I have to include the python file in my repo? If my goal is to type cmake .. and it build the 64 bit version automatically instead of needing to type cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 12 Win64", what are the minimal steps I need to take to make this happen?

Comment: For that you should contact `cmake` project, maybe there is some environment variable that would select the `Win64` version. Alternatively you can use the python version and let that select the 64bit generator. I wish cmake had some option for this.

Comment: The topic was raised within the CMake GitLab issue [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16339). Alas the issue was closed.

Comment: No that CMake GitLab issue is still open, just no change put forward to address it yet.

Answer (score 3):

For posterity.

TLDR: CMake 3.15 and above uses the environment variable `CMAKE_GENERATOR` as the default generator, it'll be used by `cmake` if no `-G` option provided. Or if it was an invalid generator CMake will choose its internal default generator.

CMake has introduced an environment variable `CMAKE_GENERATOR` controlling the default generator in version 3.15, see this [CMake 3.15 Release Notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.15.html#command-line).

And the document for the environment variable [CMAKE_GENERATOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html).