# CMake depend.make file empty

Tags: cmake

I start using CMake to build my c++ source files, I see a strange comportament when I build inicially:

'cmake ../' will gerate the directory structure

'make' will build all

any successive make command will build nothing, as expected

'cmake ../' will apparent do nothing

'make' WILL REBUILD all

any successive make command will build nothing, as expected

There is my CMakelists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -pipe")

set(var_target CommonBase)
set(var_path_source base)
project(Prj_${var_target})

file(GLOB_RECURSE var_sources ${var_path_source}/*.cpp)
add_library(${var_target} SHARED ${var_sources})

install(TARGETS ${var_target} DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/install)
```

Looking better, at first 'cmake ../' command the file 'CMakeFiles/CommonBase.dir/depend.make' is empty, and the successive make command will insert the list of file dependencies

There is something wrong with my CMakelists.txt?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

The actual cause of your problem is having the line `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)` *before* the `project` command.

The `project` command does quite a lot of work the first time it is run, and actually clears out this variable as a side-effect.  So on your first run of CMake, the compiler flags are empty, and thereafter always contain what you `set` them to.  (It's only the second time you run CMake which causes make to recompile all, not subsequent runs of CMake).

Try wrapping your `project` call with `message`s to see the effect:

```
message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS - ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
project(Prj_${var_target})
message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS - ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

Delete your CMakeCache.txt file (in your build root), then just run `cmake ..` repeatedly.

To fix this, move your `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)` to after the `project` command.

The second issue is that it's not recommended to set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` in a CMakeLists.txt.  Have a look at the comment below "[Setting default compiler in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081820/setting-default-compiler-in-cmake)", and also the link there to CMake's FAQ entry [How do I use a different compiler?](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F)

Comment: Really!
With my original config, calling "cmake .." two time resolve the issue, causing any other subsequent combination of "make" and "cmake" running as expected!


Trying your suggestion, the first call output is

    CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS - -Wall -pipe

    ...

    CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -

    ...


and the second call output

    CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS - -Wall -pipe

    CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS - -Wall -pipe

    ...


I will remove the redundant set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")


Thanks!