# Setting CMake default generator in Windows

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to learn CMake so I started with the tutorial on their website. Some functioniality like versioning with .h.in files I couldn't get to work in Visual Studio so I decided to just use CMD and CMake. Due to VS being installed CMake defaulted to creating a VS solution, after uninstalling VS it now defaults to NMake Makefiles. I want to use the MinGW generator. I know I can pass this by using the -G flag but I would like to make this to CMake's default behavior.

So that:
`cmake .` would behave the same as `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .`

I've tried the solution suggested here but it seems to not work. [Setting default compiler in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081820/setting-default-compiler-in-cmake)

Maybe I set the environtment variable wrong I don't know. Here is how I proceeded:

1. open CMake GUI
2. open the Environment Tab
3. add new Entry
4. set name to CMAKE_GENERATOR
5. set value to MinGW Makefiles
6. press OK

But still if I create a new project and run CMake it still defaults to the NMake generator.
Do you have any suggestions.

Comment: After changing your OS environment variable did you logoff and login? Or did you do set the environment variable in a cmd.exe window and run cmake from that window? If so did you delete the CMakeCache.txt file from a previous configure?

Comment: ***But still if I create a new project and run CMake it still defaults to the NMake generator*** The environment tab only affects the current instance of CMake-Gui.

Comment: The value you entered in the cmake GUI only applies to the cmake build directory you were working on at the time, you need to set an OS environment variable

Comment: See here: [https://phoenixnap.com/kb/windows-set-environment-variable](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/windows-set-environment-variable)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Control Panel
2. Search for and open "Environment Variables"
3. Click "New..."
4. Variable name: CMAKE_GENERATOR
5. Variable value: MinGW Makefiles
6. Click ok -> Click Ok
7. Restart your Terminal
8. Generate your Makefiles `~\build cmake ..`

Answer (score 0):

I had to create the CMAKE_GENERATOR variable in the Windows environment variables not in CMake.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).