# compile putty 0.78 for windows

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, compilation, putty

in the new version of putty there is no Makefile.vc or project file for visual studio. How can I compile putty under visual studio 2019? can someone help me?

[link to zipped source](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/putty-src.zip)

I tried to open the windows folder in visual studio with the following error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CMake Error at C:\Usersuser\Downloads\Compressed\putty-src\windows\CMakeLists.txt:3 (add_sources_from_current_dir):
   Unknown CMake command "add_sources_from_current_dir". C:\Users\user\Downloads\Compressed\putty-src\windows\CMakeLists.txt 3
```

Comment: download cmake and read the readme. Use command line. It builds perfectly. I don't remember even installing Microsoft C compiler, but it uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open Visual Studio or any IDE to compile the executables.

- Download cmake and make sure Visual C compiler is installed.
- Unzip the .zip file, open a command prompt where the `readme` and `CMakeLists.txt` reside
- Then, as the readme states:

> run these commands in the source directory:

```
cmake .
cmake --build .
```

In the `Debug` directory, you'll find a lot of `.exe` files.

> Then, to install in the simplest way on Linux or Mac:

```
 cmake --build . --target install
```

I didn't need that part. I suppose that it copies the executables & other files somewhere in the path.

Problem with creating a distro using Microsoft compiler is that the executables then require a lot of Microsoft runtime DLLs. For instance if you deploy the executables on other machines it may not work.

An alternative is to use `gcc` and `make` to build the executables.

First:

- install a recent gcc for windows
- install `make`

Installing a recent MinGW distribution should do it. Personally I used another gcc distribution so I had to grab `make` too.

Now, I followed [Setting default compiler in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081820/setting-default-compiler-in-cmake), the key part being to enable mingw makefiles: `-G "MinGW Makefiles"`, else cmake ignores your compiler requirements and keeps on using Microsoft compiler.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/path/to/make/make.exe -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/path/to/gcc/gcc.exe -G "MinGW Makefiles" .
```

Note that specifying full paths require that `/` are used. Backslashes conflict with escaping in cmake/make files.

Then

```
cmake --build .
```