# How to install assimp dynamic library on windows 10?

Tags: python, cmake, assimp

I'm basically trying to read a .obj file and display it in Qt in python with pyassim but the library also requires to install it's window's dynamic library.
Now when I try to run

```
cmake ..
```

in a build folder inside the library which I downloaded from here: https://github.com/assimp/assimp

It shows me this error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:55 (PROJECT):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:55 (PROJECT):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/damn1/Desktop/Working_folder/assimp/assimp-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/damn1/Desktop/Working_folder/assimp/assimp-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Any idea how to fix it considering I declared the 'PATH' VARIABLE of cmake?

Comment: Have you checked other questions about similar error message? E.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869564/cmake-on-windows).

Comment: Yeah you didn't came across yet and cmaking it with MinGW just doesn't work so I've installed visual studio now and hope using the visual studio generator will allow me to process this library without errors

Comment: Still having issues with it after downloading the VS 2019 and running cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 10"  ..

Comment: The name of generator for VS 2019 is [Visual Studio 16](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html). Also make sure to run this command under Visual Studio Command Prompt, as the error message suggests.

Comment: Thanks just found a video solving the thing you were talking about which apparently was the actual problem