# CMake & MinGW Compilation on Windows, without needing the -G "MinGW Makefiles" flag

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I want to build my C++ applications from the Windows PowerShell command line using CMake and MinGW.

When I do this in the "normal way," with these commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

CMake chooses Visual Studio as the default compiler, and doesn't generate any Makefiles for me.

I want CMake to use MinGW as the default compiler, and generate Makefiles.
**It works exactly the way that I want it to when I run these commands**, adding the -G "MinGW Makefiles" flag:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
make
```

How can I make CMake behave this way all the time, without adding the -G "MinGW Makefiles" flag?

I've tried setting up a `CMAKE_GENERATOR` environment variable in Windows, and pointing it to "`path\to\mingw\bin`", "`path\to\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe`", as well as a string that reads "`MinGW Makefile`".

None of these worked for me after running `refreshenv` and then trying to run `cmake ..` again.

Does anybody know if this is the correct environment variable to use in order to specify CMake's default behavior? If it is, what value should I be using?

Comment: Just add MinGW to the PATH variable and then try this `find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER NAMES $ENV{CXX} g++ PATHS ENV PATH NO_DEFAULT_PATH)`

Comment: According to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6439664/3440745) there is no a variable which could affect on the [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) used by default in CMake. But according to that [bugreport](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16339) the things could be changed.. in the future.

Comment: I think that what are you asking is wrong... the `CMakeFiles.txt` should be agnostic about the compiler as much as possible... this allows you to the same project for different generators.

Comment: Create an alias? An old doskey macro or alternatively a batch file cmake.bat which forwards all arguments and injects the generator first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I know this is late.** but in case someone came here and find this answer useful
all you have to do is to create a `function`  something like this:

```
function gcmake {cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"}
```

then you can simply type

```
mkdir build
cd build
gcmake ..
make
```

> tip: you can add this function to your profile so that it will be saved to any new session. you can follow this nice [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/)

Answer (score 8):

> How can I make CMake behave this way all the time, without adding the -G "MinGW Makefiles" flag?

You can't, not in any version of CMake released to date.  CMake chooses a generator before it starts evaluating any `CMakeLists.txt` files.  By default, it chooses a generator based on runtime platform and available toolsets, and command-line options are the only way presently available to influence or override CMake's choice of generator.

In comments, @Tsyvarev pointed out [an open CMake issue report](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16339) asking for the very same feature you are asking for.  The associated comment thread provides more detail, and the last comment was earlier this year.  I would guess that eventually CMake will add support for specifying a generator via environment variable, but for now, your `-G` option is the only available alternative.  You could consider scripting it if you want to save keystrokes and reduce the risk of typos.

Answer (score 2):

`cmake` uses Visual Studio generator for `MinGW` on Windows by default (even without Visual Studio!), this is the real annoying issue (`Cygwin` is not affected).

We need to work around `MinGW` only. What will be the most reliable hook for `MinGW`? I think `MSYSTEM` is very popular environment variable that will always be defined for `MinGW`.

You can place `PreLoad.cmake` in the project root with the following content:

```
if (NOT "$ENV{MSYSTEM}" STREQUAL "" AND "$ENV{VisualStudioVersion}" STREQUAL "")
  find_program (CMAKE_NINJA_BINARY NAMES "ninja")
  if (CMAKE_NINJA_BINARY)
    set (
      CMAKE_GENERATOR "Ninja"
      CACHE INTERNAL "Cmake generator"
    )
    return ()
  endif ()

  find_program (CMAKE_MAKE_BINARY NAMES "gmake" "make")
  if (CMAKE_MAKE_BINARY)
    set (
      CMAKE_GENERATOR "Unix Makefiles"
      CACHE INTERNAL "Cmake generator"
    )
    return ()
  endif ()
endif ()
```

Unfortunately this solution is not universal:

```sh
MSYSTEM=MINGW64 cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
```

```
    CMake Error: Error: generator : Unix Makefiles
    Does not match the generator used previously: Ninja
    Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory or choose a different binary directory.
```

If you are setting `CMAKE_GENERATOR` inside `PreLoad.cmake` than you are loosing ability to use `-G` `cmake` option. If you don't need this option, than this solution will be just fine.

PS It is not possible to access `-G` option value inside `PreLoad.cmake` as `CMAKE_GENERATOR` or another option. So it is not possible to add guard case like `NOT DEFINED CMAKE_GENERATOR` to check whether generator has been provided explicitly using `-G` option.