# what is the correct way to use cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, nmake

I was following instructions for compiling a software in windows as described here: https://github.com/solvespace/solvespace . But when i launch the first cmake command it points out the following :

```
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../cmake/Toolchain-mingw64.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:42 (project):
  Running

   'nmake' '-?'

  failed with:

   Impossibile trovare il file specificato


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/user/Documents/experiments/SolveSpaceFolder/solvespace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

i've alredy installed mingw64 and added to PATH, in fact it work alone. Moreover I can see that there is nmake implied. I just can't figure out what's the problem.

Comment: I think you're going to find that this is a duplicate question. Have a look here: [Using CMake on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101456/running-cmake-on-windows)

Comment: shouldn't `mingw64-make` be used not  `nmake`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove CMakeCache.txt and try to set the generator

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../cmake/Toolchain-mingw64.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

Related question: [CMake & MinGW Compilation on Windows, without needing the -G "MinGW Makefiles" flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59095842/cmake-mingw-compilation-on-windows-without-needing-the-g-mingw-makefiles-f).