# gtest and Windows 11 - Building for MinGW not Visual Studio

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw

## Problem

I would like to have gtest installed in my Windows 11 machine and run the program using MinGW for Windows 11; i.e., the gcc compiler that comes with MinGW.

I have the environment variables properly set so that I can use the MinGW commands from Powershell and the cmake environment variables too.

### What is happening.

I am trying to install gtest for Windows 11 through MinGW-w64, but when running the `cmake` command it says:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
```

I would like for it to build for MinGW-w64.

### Potentially Useful Information.

The procedure I am using to install gtest is the following:

- I go to https://github.com/google/googletest and clone the folder into the MinGW folder.
- I go into the **googletest** folder and create a **build** folder.
- I navigate into the build folder such that my location is now:

```
c:\MinGW\googletest\build\
```

- From this location, using Powershell, I run:

```
cmake ..
```

This is the message that I get:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31629.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31629.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Python: C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe (found version "3.10.5") found components: Interpreter
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/MinGW/googletest/build
```

that indicates that the compiler is for Visual Studio 17 2022. I would wish the compiler that is used to be:

```
g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
```

That is the compiler that is distributed with the version of MinGW that I have. Of course, in this case,`pthreads` will be disabled and I would not be able to run it as:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -pthread ./<whatever>.cpp -lgtest -lgtest_main
```

that is the way I like to run it from my Linux machine...that unfortunately I cannot use...as often as I'd wish.

### Final Remark(s)

If there is a way for gtest to be used using the MinGW compiler from Powershell, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong in using `-G "MinGW Makefiles"` parameter, as in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59095842/cmake-mingw-compilation-on-windows-without-needing-the-g-mingw-makefiles-f)?

Comment: Unrelated to googletest and compiler errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify a compiler in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933732/how-to-specify-a-compiler-in-cmake)

Comment: @AlexReinking still testing. Need to finish installing, but currently in a meeting. Will let you know ASAP. Thanks!